# Calculating velocity of a negative charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, acceleration, charge, velocity

From my First Year Physics Textbook:

Q1 and Q2 are stationary charges of 7.5x10^-6 Coulomb each.
Point P is a mobile charge of -1.6x10^-6 Coulomb, with mass 2x10^-6 kg.
Based on a previous part of the same question, we know that the electric field at Point P is 2.414·10^6 N/C, so we can calculate the Force.

I was asked at what speed the mobile charge will get to the Origin.

I first calculated the acceleration to be 1931200 m/s/s via F=m·a. This was confirmed by the answer key to be correct.

I then used x=0.5at^2 to calculate the time in which it will arrive to the origin (with x at 0.2), which comes out as 0.000455 seconds. Then I multiplied this by the acceleration to get 878.6 m/s.

The answer key uses another method, with different results:
In a previous part of the same question the electric potential energy at P had been calculated to be -0.96 Joule, whereas the electric potential energy at the origin was calculated to be -2.16 Joule. They take the difference, i.e. 1.2 Joule, to be the kinetic energy, and then via K=0.5m·v^2, calculate the v to be 1095 m/s.

I have been wrecking my head over this, because I am pretty sure my methodology is solid. Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: The force felt by the particle isnt constant and so you can't use the constant acceleration formula, but energy is conserved

Comment: @Triatticus That looks like it should be an answer